# How to test laravel pipeline

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing

I am using pipeline to filter messages.

```
$value = app(Pipeline::class)
        ->send($value)
        ->through([
            HtmlAttributeFilter::class,
            ProfanityFilter::class,
            RemoveTags::class,
        ])
        ->thenReturn();
```

I want to test this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use Closure;

class HtmlAttributeFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    /**
     * Handles attribute filtering removes unwanted attributes
     * @param $text
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($text, Closure $next)
    {
        $text = str_replace('javascript:', '', $text);
        $text = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/si", '<$1$2>', $text);
        return $next($text);
    }
}
```

I test this code by defining custom closure but I am not sure I am doing it in right way. I wanted to mock but I couldn't figure out how to mock this object. Did anyone test pipelines before? Any help would be highly appricated.

This is how I test it

```
$callable = function (string $text) {
        return $text;
    };
    $text = "<html lang='tr'><link href='https://www.example.com'></html>";
    $expectedText = "<html><link></html>";
    $obj = new HtmlAttributeFilter();
    $filteredText = $obj->handle($text, $callable);
    $this->assertEquals($expectedText, $filteredText);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think giving it a custom closure is the right thing to do e.g. like:

```
public function testHtmlAttributeFilterDoesSomething() {
   $next = function ($result) {
        $this->assertEquals('expected value', $result);
        
   };
   app()->make(HtmlAttributeFilter::class)->handle('given value', $next);
}
```

I don't think you need to test the entire pipeline as long as each constituent part is tested because Laravel includes tests that test whether the pipeline logic is working as intended

Comment: Thanks it is much cleaner